# To show a quotient of polynomial is an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to show:
$$\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}\limits^{n}{(x^{m+i}-1)}}{\prod\limits_{i=1}\limits^{n}{(x^{i}-1)}}\in \mathbb{Z},\text{ for } m,n,x\in\mathbb{Z}, m\geq n\geq 1.$$

Thanks.

Edited:
I’m not sure if it’s true for arbitrary integer x. If it’s not, the original problem sets x=10, and I’m still trying to figure out.

Comment: How is it possible ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, it’s actually my guess, for arbitrary x the conclusion holds. In the original problem, x is fixed to 10 in which case I also can’t figure it out.  I’m editing the problem now.

Comment: @SebastianMonnet Summing index $i$ cannot take 2 since n=1, and $x^{mi}-1$ is not what I want, otherwise it can be divided by the denominator respectively.

Comment: @SebastianMonnet That's not a counterexample. $n=1$, $m=1$, $x=2$ yields the value $3$. Assigning a value to $i$ doesn't make sense, $i$ is the index of the sum.

Comment: @yuanqing You may want to exclude, for obvious reasons, the values $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: @jjagmath lol good point, I'll remove my previous comments:)

Comment: The title winds up being a misleading statement of the problem's goal.  The better way to phrase it would be that the *rational function* takes integer values at all $x\neq \pm 1$, which is quite a bit different from a claim that the rational function *is* an integer.  Also you neglected to exclude $\pm 1$ from the evaluation in the body of the Question, despite the prior Comments about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show that
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (x^i-1)\bigg|\prod_{i=1}^n(x^{m+i}-1)$$
as polynomials in $x$. Indeed, factor the left side over $\mathbb C$; the product becomes a product over terms $(x-\omega)$ where $\omega$ is a root of unity. If $\omega$ is a primitive $d$th root of unity for some $d$, then this term occurs in the factors $x^i-1$ whenever $d\mid i$, and so $(x-\omega)$ is a factor of the left side with exponent $\lfloor n/d\rfloor$. It's a factor of the right side with exponent
$$\left\lfloor\frac{m+n}d\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac md\right\rfloor,$$
so we need only prove
$$\left\lfloor\frac{m+n}d\right\rfloor \geq \left\lfloor \frac md\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac nd\right\rfloor.$$
In fact, $\lfloor \alpha+\beta\rfloor\geq \lfloor\alpha\rfloor+\lfloor\beta\rfloor$ for any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$, since $\alpha+\beta\geq\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+\lfloor\beta\rfloor$ and the right side is an integer.

Comment: For this to be an answer of the OP question, you'll need to prove that the divisibility happens as polynomials in $\Bbb Z [x]$, not only in $\Bbb C [x]$

Comment: @jjagmath Any monic integer polynomials which have a quotient in $\mathbb C[x]$ have a quotient in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: I know that, but I don't see any mention of that in the proof.